# Problema con if else en php

Tags: php, condiciones, else

Estoy haciendo el siguiente if else en php para cuando detecte que hay un usuario logueado muestre un menú y cuando no lo está muestre otro. El problema es que me da un error en el primer corchete `}` justo antes del else:

> (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebBurger\lib\inc\header.php on line 115)

Ya que me debo haber dejado algún tag del php o corchete mal, pero no sé verlo. Si me podríais ayudar. Muchas gracias!

Las funciones `isUserLoggedIn` y `nombreUsuario` están en el `UsuarioController.php` que también adjunto. Los href están mal aún los tengo que hacer bien, no los tengáis en cuenta.

```html
<html>

<body>



    <header class="page-header font-small unique-color-dark">

        <?php 
        $usuarioc = new UsuarioController();
        if($usuarioc->isUserLoggedIn())?>{

        <div class="header text-left py-5" role="navigation">

        <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu_item_logo">
        <img src="/WebBurger/public/img/logoreducido.png">
        </li>
        <li class="menu_item">
        <a href="/WebBurger/public/index.php">INICIO</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu_item">
        <a href="../../public/avisolegal.php">LA CARTA</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu_item">
        <a href="../../public/cookies.php">CONOCE AL PERSONAL</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu_item">
        <a href="../../public/protecciondatos.php">CONTACTA</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu_item">
        <a href="../../public/protecciondatos.php">HAZ TU RESERVA</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu_item">
        <a href="../../public/protecciondatos.php">HAZ TU PEDIDO</a>
        </li>

        </ul>
        Bienvenido, <?=$usuarioc->nombreUsuario()?>
        <a href="https://google.com">Perfil</a>
        <a href="/WebBurger/public/forms/logout.php">Salir</a>

        </div>


     <?php } else { ?>

     <div class="header text-left py-5" role="navigation">
        <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu_item_logo">
        <img src="/WebBurger/public/img/logoreducido.png">
        </li>
        <li class="menu_item">
        <a href="/WebBurger/public/index.php">INICIO</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu_item">
        <a href="../../public/avisolegal.php">LA CARTA</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu_item">
        <a href="../../public/cookies.php">CONOCE AL PERSONAL</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu_item">
        <a href="../../public/protecciondatos.php">CONTACTA</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu_item">
        <a href="../../public/protecciondatos.php">HAZ TU RESERVA</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu_item">
        <a href="../../public/protecciondatos.php">HAZ TU PEDIDO</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu_item">
        <i class="fas fa-user white-text mr-4">
        </i>
        <a href="/WebBurger/public/accedeoregistro.php">ACCEDE O REGÍSTRATE
        </a>
        </li>


        </ul>

     </div>

        } <?php  ?>



    </header>

</body>




</html>
```

UsuarioController.php

```html
<?php 

require_once(__DIR__.'/../model/DB/UsuarioDB.php');

class UsuarioController{

public function nombreUsuario(){
        return $_SESSION['usuario'];
    }
    
    public function isUserLoggedIn(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['usuario']) 
            && $_SESSION['usuario']!= null 
            && $_SESSION['usuario'] != ""){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Vista navegador

[image: header]

Comment: Tienes la llave del `if` fuera del código interpretado por **PHP**: `if($usuarioc->isUserLoggedIn())?>{` cuando debería ser: `if($usuarioc->isUserLoggedIn()) {?>`

Comment: También tienes mal el cierre del `else`, tienes:  `} <?php  ?>`cuando debería ser: `<?php }  ?>`

Comment: Es verdad, gracias, ahora sí, el problema ahora es que me va bien pero cuando ejecuto no me sale el header con el menú bien. Adjunto una foto en el hilo de la pregunta, se me queda como en la foto y le doy al f12 y no me da ningún error. @Zito_MA

Comment: ¿Puedes actualizar el HTML?

Comment: Sí, a que te refieres exactamente? básicamente lo que tengo más es el head, con los enlaces a las librerías y el style (css)

Comment: ya está, nada, solucionado, era una tontería. @Zito_MA

Comment: Perfecto, me alegra haberte ayudado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple vista, el corchete del if, lo tienes después de las etiquetas de php:

```
<?php 
        $usuarioc = new UsuarioController();
        if($usuarioc->isUserLoggedIn())?>{ --> ...LoggedIn()){ ?>
```

Y te pasa exactamente lo mismo, con la etiqueta de cierre del else:

```
 } <?php  ?> --> <?php } ?>
```